# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCoreExtension"

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to do `pod install` but it says error like:

> No podspec found for `RNFBAnalytics` in `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics`

I found a solution that says `yarn add @react-native-firebase/analytics && cd ios && pod install --repo-update` and it eliminates above error and shows another similar error like:

> [!] No podspec found for `RNFBCrashlytics` in `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics`

Again, fixed with a similar method `yarn add @react-native-firebase/crashlytics&& cd ios && pod install --repo-update`

Afterwards, it shows:

> [!] No podspec found for `react-native-fbsdk` in `../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk`

This time also, I did `yarn add react-native-fbsdk&& cd ios && pod install --repo-update`

And finally it shows:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCoreExtension":
> In Podfile:
> RNFBCrashlytics (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics`) was resolved to 15.3.0, which depends on
> FirebaseCoreExtension (= 8.12.1)
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `FirebaseCoreExtension (= 8.12.1)`.
> You have either:
>
> - out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
> - mistyped the name or version.
> - not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

From the error, I would like to know several things:

What is `FirebaseCoreExtension`?

Is it an npm package? ( I don't think so).

How can I fix the error?

I have been looking for solutions by searching for similar cases but they don't give me any clear and correct answer.
I deleted `Podfile.lock` and reinstall Pods by `pod install`. Also deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled it by `yarn install`.
And I tried:
`pod deintegrate`
`pod install`
`pod update`
but no luck yet.
FYI, I experience this issue after I migrate the project from for Xcode 12 to Xcode13.

Can anyone help?

Don't hesitate to leave any comment and I can upvote any answer that helps even a bit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to `/ios/{projectName}.xcworkspace`.

And make sure you have this code in your `/ios/{projectName}/AppDelegate.m` file.

```
#import <Firebase.h>
.....
.....
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [FIRApp configure];
  // ....
}
```

Follow the exact procedure given in their [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/).

Comment: Hi @vinayr, please check another issue and let me know if you could help with it please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345616/xcode-lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-redefinition-of-module

Comment: I appreciate that you provided a cool solution which worked like a charm.

Comment: I am still getting same error even after doing what you suggested here. I specified this pod spec `pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', '~> 6.27.0'`. But still getting error. Any alternatives?

Comment: You may be  hitting an issue where you need to udpate your pod repo. Try running `pod repo update` then you may want to do a `gem install cocoapods` for good measure. Then try your `pod install` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

by updating the @react-native-firebase/app fixed this issue for me

```
"yarn add @react-native-firebase/app"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave the firebase dependencies to the same version, to avoid possible collisions between versions, for them core (app), like this:

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^16.4.4",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.4",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^16.4.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

If the answers above don't work for you, it's possible you just need to clean your Pods and podfile.lock and try again

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it in my case was to delete the `Podfile.lock` file at `/ios` folder.

Then I run:

```
npx pod-install
```

and it updated the dependencies automatically:

```
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec`
[Hermes] Using the release tarball from Maven Central
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase 10.21.0 (was 10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop 10.22.0 (was 10.21.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth 10.21.0 (was 10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop 10.22.0 (was 10.21.0)
Installing FirebaseCore 10.21.0 (was 10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension 10.21.0 (was 10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal 10.22.0 (was 10.21.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore 10.21.0 (was 10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestoreInternal 10.22.0 (was 10.21.0)
```