# Xcode: lexical or preprocessor issue - redefinition of module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have been looking for a solution to fix the below error.

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group - Redefinition of module 'fmt'

[image: Navigation area that shows the errors]

FYI, I attached the screenshot to show you the errors.
I have gone through all solutions on `stackoverflow` and `github` but none of them gives a clear and relevant solution. As you can see, there are 12 errors in two categories.
One is `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group` and another is `Parse Issue`. I have focused mainly on searching for the solution to first category issues but they all `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - ***.h file not found` errors. So no helpful one found yet. I am building it in Xcode 13.4.1 after migrating from Xcode 12.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented `flipper_post_install(installer)` in `Podfile`.
Afterwards, it gives another `interpolate is not a function` error but anyway it cleared the `lexical or preprocessor issue` error away.